# fix sliding accurately based on specific proportion ? CSS/JS

Tags: javascript, css

**The project:**
I made a 3 items slider just using CSS and JS. I'm trying to adjust the proportion of one item to make sliding based on this proportion.

**The problem:**
the proportion isn't fixed and there is a slight space from the left side of all items and between items themselves. It seems they have borders that take a tiny space. and that space also affects sliding itself. I don't know if it's a CSS or JS problem!

Source Code on [Codepen](https://codepen.io/MedooEgy/pen/JjENaLZ?editors=0110)

**HTML**

```
<div id="slider">
  
<div class="SlideContainer">
<div class="img">
<img src="https://www.nicepng.com/png/detail/11-112605_punk-cat-berkley-cats-illustrations.png">
</div>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">1</h1>
</div>
  
<div class="SlideContainer">
  <div class="img">
<img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/84/78/b9/8478b93283dc6eac074d437097a9fe74.jpg">  
  </div>
  <h1 style="text-align:center;">2</h1>
</div>

   ...... etc

</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#slider {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

.SlideContainer{ 
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  height: 99% ;
  margin: .5% 0;
  width: 33%;
  display: inline-block;
}

.img {
  overflow: hidden; 
  max-width:200px;
  max-height:200px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: block;
  margin: 10px auto 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}
.img img{
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

**JS**

```
var Container  = document.getElementById("slider");
var unitWidth = (Container.offsetWidth/3);
var slidesNo = (document.getElementsByClassName("SlideContainer").length - 2);
var i = 0;


var positionInfo = Container.getBoundingClientRect();
var height = positionInfo.height;
var width = (positionInfo.width/3);


function SlideLoop(){
  
     var interval = setInterval(function(){
          Container.scrollTo((unitWidth * i), 0);  
        //Container.scrollBy(unitWidth, 0); 
          i++;
          if(i == slidesNo) {
            i = 0;
            clearInterval(interval);SlideLoop();
          }
      }, 1500);

};

SlideLoop();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is with using `white-space: nowrap;` in the slider and `display: inline-block;` in the slider items.

Using such methods to display items is not recommended because it would cause strange unexpected behavior. I suggest you learn flexbox. [This is a great and easy guide](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) that will help you.

as for your problem, change those css elements like this and it should work propely:

```
#slider {
  height: 500px;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0 .5%;
  overflow: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
  display: flex; /* displays items horizontally */
}

.SlideContainer{ 
  vertical-align: top;
  background-color: purple;
  color: white;
  height: 99% ;
  margin: .5% 0;
  min-width:33%; /* force the minimum width of items */
}
```

Comment: thank you, sir, your answer helped me a lot. it's really better to use the flexbox layout. But, it still wasn't 100% fixed. However, I found a very accurate solution by removing padding: 0 .5%; from #slider and increase.SlideContainer to min-width:33.3%;. and for JS I found also an alternative for using scrollTo or scrollBy which is scrollIntoView. and all of these steps come up with really accurate result. you can check out my link again to see my new solution. thanks again.